# Problems texturing a cube

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures

im trying to make a cube with a different texture on each face.

I have the front face and the rear face working now. Now i am trying to make the right face of the cube. But something is going wrong, because i got the right face done but the texture is showing with errors (it's like stretched and shredded), i have something bad in my code and i dont know what.

This is my code

```
public class Cube {

private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;//Vertices
private FloatBuffer textureBuffer;//Texture coordinates
private ByteBuffer indexBuffer;//Indices
private int[] textures = new int[6];//Texture pointer

private float vertices[] = { //8 vertices of the cube
        -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, // 0
        1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,  // 1
        -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,  // 2
        1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,   // 3

        -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,// 4
        1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, // 5
        -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, // 6
        1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,  // 7
};

private byte indices[] = { //Faces definition
        0,1,2, 1,3,2, //front face (*)
        6,7,5, 6,5,4, //rear face (**)
        1,5,3, 5,7,3, //right face (***) //problems here
};

private float texture[] = {//Mapping coordinates for the vertices
        0.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, 0.0f,

        0.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, 0.0f,

        0.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, 0.0f,
};

public Cube() 
{
    ByteBuffer byteBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
    byteBuf.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    vertexBuffer = byteBuf.asFloatBuffer();
    vertexBuffer.put(vertices);
    vertexBuffer.position(0);

    byteBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(texture.length * 4);
    byteBuf.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    textureBuffer = byteBuf.asFloatBuffer();
    textureBuffer.put(texture);
    textureBuffer.position(0);

    indexBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indices.length);
    indexBuffer.put(indices);
    indexBuffer.position(0);
}

public void draw(GL10 gl) {
    //Point to our buffers
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    //Set the face rotation
    gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CCW);
    //Enable the vertex and texture state
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
    gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureBuffer);
    //para que no pinte los poligonos que no se ven
    //gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++) //<6 por que tenemos 6 texturas que queremos poner en las 6 caras de un cubo.
    {
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[i]);
        indexBuffer.position(6*i); //como cada dos triangulos (cuadrado) forman una cara, estos dos triangulos son 6 indices del array de indices, por lo tanto avanzamos 6 posiciones en el indexBuffer para pintar el siguiente cuadrado.
        gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, indexBuffer); //el segundo parametro es 6 por que solo queremos pintar una cara (cuadrado) por textura.
    }
    //gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE); //para que no pinte los poligonos que no se ven
    //Disable the client state before leaving
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
}

public void loadGLTexture(GL10 gl, Context context) {
    loadTexture(gl,context,R.drawable.s1,0);
    loadTexture(gl,context,R.drawable.s2,1);
    loadTexture(gl,context,R.drawable.s3,2);
    loadTexture(gl,context,R.drawable.s4,3);
    loadTexture(gl,context,R.drawable.s5,4);
    loadTexture(gl,context,R.drawable.s6,5);
}

public void loadTexture(GL10 gl, Context context, int drawable, int textureNumber)
{
    //Get the texture from the Android resource directory
    InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(drawable);
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try {
        //BitmapFactory is an Android graphics utility for images
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    } finally {
        //Always clear and close
        try {
            is.close();
            is = null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
    //Generate one texture pointer...
    gl.glGenTextures(1, textures, textureNumber);
    //...and bind it to our array
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[textureNumber]);
    //Create Nearest Filtered Texture
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
    //Different possible texture parameters, e.g. GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_REPEAT);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_REPEAT);
    //Use the Android GLUtils to specify a two-dimensional texture image from our bitmap
    GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
    //Clean up
    bitmap.recycle();
}
}
```

Comment: Is your texture's dimensions power of two ? Like 512*512.

Comment: yes, it is, all the textures have the same dimensions, are the faces of a dice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In OpenGL a vertex is the combination of a location and/or a texture coordinate and/or a colour and/or arbitrarily more attributes. So although you have 12 texture coordinates listed, all OpenGL gets from your data is 8 distinct vertices, each with a position and a texture coordinate.

Your right face is composed of two triangles, one with vertices 1, 5 and 3 and one with vertices 5, 7 and 3. So that's conceptually the same as a quad with vertices 1, 5, 7 and 3.

From your own data, that quad has vertices:

```
location: 1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f; coordinate: 1.0f, 1.0f
location: 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f; coordinate: 1.0f, 1.0f
location: 1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f; coordinate: 1.0f, 0.0f
location: 1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f; coordinate: 1.0f, 0.0f
```

You'd therefore expect it to display the one dimensional straight line that runs along the right hand side of your texture, stretched out across the entire face. Is that what you're seeing?

If you want to supply unique texture coordinates for the corners of the side faces, you need to give them unique vertices (albeit that they'll be located exactly on top of other vertices).

Comment: please can you explain it a little more?, did you mean that i need to declare 24 vertices (and not 8) if i am using different textures/colors per face of the cube?

Comment: 24 would be the upper limit, that could ensure complete generality. What most people do in practice is skinning — which is to figure out the net of the object (in the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(polyhedron) sense), then paint the texture according to that. You end up duplicating some vertex locations but not all.