# Coord texture array does not works on a cube

Tags: arrays, opengl, coordinates, textures

the purpose of my program is to load and display a simple cube with the same texture on each face. the problem is the 2 first faces (front, rear) are good. I tried several combinations of vertices in the textures array but it doesn't work. I don't know if I need to add more vertices in the textures array or change the order or change the indices array.

```
#define OFFSET_BUFFER(bytes) ((GLfloat *)NULL + bytes)

float vertices[] =
{
    -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, // 0 
    1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,  // 1 
    -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,  // 2 
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,   // 3 

    -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,// 4 
    1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, // 5 
    -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, // 6 
    1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,  // 7 
}; 

GLubyte indices[] =
{
    0,1,2, 1,3,2, //front face
    6,7,5, 6,5,4, //rear face
    1,5,3, 5,7,3, //problem on the right face
    //2,3,6, 3,6,7,
    //2,4,0, 2,4,6
    0,5,1, 5,4,0
}; 

float textures[] =
{
    0.0f, 1.0f,//0
    1.0f, 1.0f,//1
    0.0f, 0.0f,//2
    1.0f, 0.0f,//3

    0.0f, 1.0f,//0
    1.0f, 1.0f,//1
    0.0f, 0.0f,//2
    1.0f, 0.0f,//3
}; 

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_WM_SetCaption("Texture Mapping",NULL);
    SDL_SetVideoMode(500, 500, 32, SDL_OPENGL);

    bool continuer = true;
    SDL_Event event;
    GLuint texCube;

    glClearDepth(1.0f);
    glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(70.0f, (float)500.0f / (float)500.0f, 1.0f, 3000.0f);
    glewInit();

    texCube = loadTexture("caisse.jpg");
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texCube);

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    while (continuer)
    {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        SDL_WaitEvent(&event);
        switch(event.type)
        {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                continuer = false;
        }

        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();

        gluLookAt(0.0f, 0.0f, 3.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

        //Draw Cube ---------------------------------------

        glPushMatrix();
        glRotatef(90.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);

        glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
        glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, textures);

        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 24, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, indices);

        glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

        //-------------------------------------------------

        glPopMatrix();

        glFlush();
        SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();
    }

    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Coord texture array does not works correctly with glDrawElements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10401605/coord-texture-array-does-not-works-correctly-with-gldrawelements)

Comment: It's not exactly the same problem but I searched a long time without any result and I didn't find a tuto to help me. I'm on this problem since 2 days. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your corners are sharing texture coordinates, which just isn't going to work.
you should have 4 vertices for each face, as the texture coordinates for each corner will be different depending on the face.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried with glDrawArrays with just a vertices array and textures array and this solution works (with four vertices for each face (vertices[] and textures[])). But wanted to find a better solution with infdices array to factorize my code. Do you mean in the present case I have to add vertices in vertices[] and in textures[]?

Comment: Yes, because each index that you specify refers to the same vertex in both the position and textures array. even though there are only 8 corners in a cube, and 4 corners in a square, each corner in the cube won't have the same texture coordinate for each side. 
If you try to draw it on paper you'll see what I mean

Comment: yes it was what I had effectively seen. But I thought it might have worked with fewer vertices using the indices array (factorization). So this kind of method with the indices array with only 8 vertices for the vertices array works only with vertices array. If I want to add textures layer I have to change vertices buffers like you said (so 24 vertices) and create a texture buffer with 24 vertices too. Is it right? But in this case glDrawArrays function is sufficient. Indices array is useless. Thank you again for your answer.

Comment: There may be another way, but as far as I know, that's the only way (I'm eager to find out if there is a way). Many more complex meshes will have shared vertices that have both the same position and texture coordinate (such as a character, or terrain), so the indices wouldn't be uselses

Comment: I fixed my problem with your solution. In fact it is not useless like you said. It's better with indice array. It's more readable. So thank you very much for all your answers and your patience with me. Bye.

Answer (score 1):

The solution of my problem is the following code :

```
#define OFFSET_BUFFER(bytes) ((GLfloat *)NULL + bytes)

float angle = 0.0f;

float vertices[72] =
{
    -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,//VO - 0
    1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,//V1 - 1
    -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,//V2 - 2
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,//V3 - 3

    -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,//V4 - 4
    1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,//V5 - 5
    -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,//V6 - 6
    1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,//V7 - 7

    -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,//V2 - 8
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,//V3 - 9
    -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,//V6 - 10
    1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,//V7 - 11

    -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,//VO - 12
    1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,//V1 - 13
    -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,//V4 - 14
    1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,//V5 - 15

    -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,//VO - 16
    -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,//V2 - 17
    -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,//V4 - 18
    -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,//V6 - 19

    1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,//V1 - 20
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,//V3 - 21
    1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,//V5 - 22
    1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,//V7 - 23
}; 

GLubyte indices[36] =
{
    0,1,2, 1,3,2,
    6,7,5, 6,5,4,
    8,9,10, 9,10,11,
    12,13,14, 13,14,15,
    17,16,18, 17,18,19,
    20,21,22, 21,22,23
}; 

float textures[48] =
{
    0.0f, 1.0f,//0
    1.0f, 1.0f,//1
    0.0f, 0.0f,//2
    1.0f, 0.0f,//3

    0.0f, 1.0f,//0
    1.0f, 1.0f,//1
    0.0f, 0.0f,//2
    1.0f, 0.0f,//3

    0.0f, 1.0f,//0
    1.0f, 1.0f,//1
    0.0f, 0.0f,//2
    1.0f, 0.0f,//3

    0.0f, 1.0f,//0
    1.0f, 1.0f,//1
    0.0f, 0.0f,//2
    1.0f, 0.0f,//3

    0.0f, 1.0f,//0
    1.0f, 1.0f,//1
    0.0f, 0.0f,//2
    1.0f, 0.0f,//3

    0.0f, 1.0f,//0
    1.0f, 1.0f,//1
    0.0f, 0.0f,//2
    1.0f, 0.0f,//3
}; 

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_WM_SetCaption("Texture Mapping",NULL);
    SDL_SetVideoMode(500, 500, 32, SDL_OPENGL);

    bool continuer = true;
    SDL_Event event;
    GLuint texCube;

    glClearDepth(1.0f);
    glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(70.0f, (float)500.0f / (float)500.0f, 1.0f, 3000.0f);
    glewInit();

    texCube = loadTexture("caisse.jpg");
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texCube);

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    while (continuer)
    {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        SDL_WaitEvent(&event);
        switch(event.type)
        {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                continuer = false;
        }

        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();

        gluLookAt(0.0f, 0.0f, 3.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

        //Draw Cube ---------------------------------------

        glPushMatrix();
        glRotatef(angle, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);

        glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
        glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, textures);

        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 48, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, indices);

        glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

        //-------------------------------------------------

        angle += 1.0f;

        glPopMatrix();

        glFlush();
        SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();
    }

    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

And the solution with VBO :

```
#define OFFSET_BUFFER(bytes) ((GLfloat *)NULL + bytes)

float angle = 0.0f;

float vertices[72] =
{
    -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,//VO - 0
    1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,//V1 - 1
    -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,//V2 - 2
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,//V3 - 3

    -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,//V4 - 4
    1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,//V5 - 5
    -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,//V6 - 6
    1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,//V7 - 7

    -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,//V2 - 8
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,//V3 - 9
    -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,//V6 - 10
    1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,//V7 - 11

    -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,//VO - 12
    1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,//V1 - 13
    -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,//V4 - 14
    1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,//V5 - 15

    -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,//VO - 16
    -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,//V2 - 17
    -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,//V4 - 18
    -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,//V6 - 19

    1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,//V1 - 20
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,//V3 - 21
    1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,//V5 - 22
    1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,//V7 - 23
}; 

GLubyte indices[36] =
{
    0,1,2, 1,3,2,
    6,7,5, 6,5,4,
    8,9,10, 9,10,11,
    12,13,14, 13,14,15,
    17,16,18, 17,18,19,
    20,21,22, 21,22,23
}; 

float textures[48] =
{
    0.0f, 1.0f,//0
    1.0f, 1.0f,//1
    0.0f, 0.0f,//2
    1.0f, 0.0f,//3

    0.0f, 1.0f,//0
    1.0f, 1.0f,//1
    0.0f, 0.0f,//2
    1.0f, 0.0f,//3

    0.0f, 1.0f,//0
    1.0f, 1.0f,//1
    0.0f, 0.0f,//2
    1.0f, 0.0f,//3

    0.0f, 1.0f,//0
    1.0f, 1.0f,//1
    0.0f, 0.0f,//2
    1.0f, 0.0f,//3

    0.0f, 1.0f,//0
    1.0f, 1.0f,//1
    0.0f, 0.0f,//2
    1.0f, 0.0f,//3

    0.0f, 1.0f,//0
    1.0f, 1.0f,//1
    0.0f, 0.0f,//2
    1.0f, 0.0f,//3
}; 

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_WM_SetCaption("Texture Mapping",NULL);
    SDL_SetVideoMode(500, 500, 32, SDL_OPENGL);

    bool continuer = true;
    SDL_Event event;
    GLuint texCube;
    GLuint VBO[3];

    glClearDepth(1.0f);
    glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(70.0f, (float)500.0f / (float)500.0f, 1.0f, 3000.0f);
    glewInit();

    texCube = loadTexture("caisse.jpg");

    glGenBuffers(2, VBO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO[0]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO[1]);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO[2]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(textures), textures, GL_STATIC_DRAW);


    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    while (continuer)
    {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        SDL_WaitEvent(&event);
        switch(event.type)
        {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                continuer = false;
        }

        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();

        gluLookAt(0.0f, 0.0f, 3.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

        //Draw Cube ---------------------------------------

        glPushMatrix();
        glRotatef(angle, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texCube);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO[0]);
        glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, OFFSET_BUFFER(0));
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO[2]);
        glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, OFFSET_BUFFER(0));

        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 48, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, OFFSET_BUFFER(0));

        glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

        //-------------------------------------------------

        angle += 1.0f;

        glPopMatrix();

        glFlush();
        SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();
    }

    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to save a few bytes, you can still factorize a few vertices (16 vertices instead of 24). You consider your cube without two opposite faces and add these two faces separately. Here is an IQM model which does just that:

```
# Inter-Quake Export 

mesh "Cube" 

material "cube.tga" 

vp 1 1 -1 
vn 1 1 -1 
vt 0 0 

vp 1 -1 -1 
vn 1 -1 -1 
vt 0 1 

vp -1 -1 -1 
vn -1 -1 -1 
vt 1 1 

vp -1 1 -1 
vn -1 1 -1 
vt 1 0 

vp 1 1 1 
vn 1 1 1 
vt 1 0 

vp -1 1 1 
vn -1 1 1 
vt 0 0 

vp -1 -1 1 
vn -1 -1 1 
vt 0 1 

vp 1 -1 1 
vn 1 -1 1 
vt 1 1 

vp 1 1 -1 
vn 1 1 -1 
vt 0 0 

vp -1 1 -1 
vn -1 1 -1 
vt 1 0 

vp -1 1 1 
vn -1 1 1 
vt 1 1 

vp 1 1 1 
vn 1 1 1 
vt 0 1 

vp 1 1 -1 
vn 1 1 -1 
vt 0 0 

vp -1 1 -1 
vn -1 1 -1 
vt 1 0 

vp -1 1 1 
vn -1 1 1 
vt 1 1 

vp 1 1 1 
vn 1 1 1 
vt 0 1 

fm 0 1 2 
fm 0 2 3 
fm 0 4 7 
fm 0 7 1 
fm 4 6 7 
fm 4 5 6 
fm 5 2 6 
fm 5 3 2 
fm 8 9 10 
fm 8 10 11 
fm 12 15 14 
fm 12 14 13
```